# "easy counting argument" to show some large subset is not a subcover

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading Camina and Evan's paper "[Some Infinite Permutation Modules](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/42/1/15/1544794)".
In the proof of Lemma 2.2, they use the following combinatorial argument:

> [...] $S$ is a collection of $k$-subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $\bigcup S$ has greater than $2 k$ elements. Then an easy counting argument shows that there is a subset $S_0$ of $S$ with $|S_0| > |S|/2$ and an element $v \in \bigcup S \setminus \bigcup S_0$. [...]

I can convince myself of this on small examples. For example, when $|S| = 3$ the requirement that $|\bigcup S| > 2k$ makes it impossible for any 2-element subset $S_0 \subseteq S$ to be a subcover of $\bigcup S$. I'm afraid I fail to see the "easy counting argument" for the general case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we can't find a $v$ that is covered by less than $\frac{|S|}{2}$ subsets.

Let $n(v)$ be the number of subsets of $S$ that contain an element $v$.
Then the sum of the $n(v)$ for all elements $v$ is equal to $2k$

$$\sum_{v\in \bigcup S} n(v) > 2k\frac{|S|}{2} = k|S|$$

Moreover, because each subset has $k$ elements:
$$\sum_{v\in \bigcup S} n(v) = k|S|$$

Hence the contradiction.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how $n(v)$ is defined for $v \in \bigcup S$ --- is $n(v) = |\{S_0 \subseteq S \mid \bigcup S_0 \ni v\}|$ ? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I can use contain if it is clearer,

Comment: Do you mind explaining how the last equality follows?

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong: wouldn't the negation of our conclusion say that all $S_0 \subseteq S$ whose size is bigger than $|S|/2$ contain all $v$; so $n(v) \geq \binom{|S|}{|S|} + \binom{|S|}{|S|-1} + \dots + \binom{|S|}{m}$ where $m$ is the least integer above $|S|/2$?

Comment: @JingjieYang every subset contributes one in the sum for each element in contains, so it contributes $k$ in total. Because there are $|S|$ subsets, they contribute $k|S|$ in total. I don't get your last comment.

Comment: I see where I was confused — I was mistaken in my first comment, $n(v)$ should be, say, $|\{X \in S \mid X \ni v\}|$. I had thought a 'subset of S' was a subcollection of $k$-element sets, as opposed to a $k$-element set in $S$. Thank you for the terse argument!